# Как переопределить свойство типа string если геттер должен вернуть ToUpper() от базового свойства?

Tags: c#, классы, override

Существует базовый класс `String` и производный `CappitalLettersString`. Можно ли как то описать getter свойства `Text`, или как-то схитрить, чтобы не получить исключение StackOverflow?

Насколько я понимаю переписанный геттер не может ссылаться на самого себя, получается getter ссылается на getter.

```
internal abstract class String
{
    public abstract string Text { get; set; }
}
```

```
internal class CapitalLettersString : String
{
    public override string Text { get => Text.ToUpper(); set { } }
}
```

Comment: Переименуйте класс `String`, он конфликтует с `System.String`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для обращения к члену базового типа нужно использовать ключевое слово `base`:

```
internal class CapitalLettersString : String
{
    public override string Text { get => base.Text.ToUpper(); set { } }
}
```

Хотя, конечно, в конкретно вашем примере это не сработает, потому что наследование происходит от `String`, в котором базовой реализации не существует из-за ключевого слова `abstract`. Но в общем случае то, что вы хотите сделать, делается через `base`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, поверить не могу. Всегда на всякий случай указывал base, даже когда компилятор этого не требовал, а тут как на зло забыл...